# Pine Script; Is it possible to set a label's y location to the top of the chart?

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to set a label's y location to the top of the chart, similar to the plotshape function which allowed us to set it at the top using location.top. With Pine v4 the only options we have that are similar are yloc.abovebar, but it still isn't cutting it.

If there is no direct way of doing it, could there be a more complex and indirect way such as using the highest high on the visible chart (rather than a fixed amount of bars back) or somehow retrieving the y location from a shape plotted at the top of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. The concept is in the air but no ETA.

As Pine has no visibility on the chart and the number of bars it contains, the best compromise I know to achieve your objective is to use something like `highest(200)[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I guess I'll just use the highest high of a set number of bars back as a temporary solution as you suggest. I'm looking forward to them releasing the functionality, it's pretty basic and very useful.

Comment: I just added an atr(10) to the highest high of the past 10 bars so that it doesn't get in the way, it's a good workaround for now.